# Is there any way to control my ultabooks accelerometers without using winRT APIs?

Tags: .net, c#, com, wpf

I read somewhere that it can be done with something called "COM". I don't understand what that means but I'm sure its possible.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/com/default.mspx

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model

Comment: Where did you read this?  What is possible entirely depends on the hardware. For instance a device running Windows RT, has no choice, but to use the WinRT APIs.

Answer (score 0):

To access the sensors through COM you need to create an [`ISensorManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object, which will allow you to interact with the sensors.  See also: [Getting Started](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at MSDN.

---

Edit: Below is the WinRT way of doing the same thing.

You'll need to use [`Windows.Devices.Sensors.Accelerometer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br225687) to access the sensor.  Samples can be found either through [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465272), or through Microsoft's [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/v1.0.5/Samples/Accelerometer/cs).

Comment: but that's only through winRT isn't it? Is there no way through COM?